# Golang MySQL driver with AWS RDS ca cert not valid with CNAME

Tags: mysql, go, amazon-rds

I'm attempting to connect my golang application with `AWS RDS` via a SSL connection using the MySQL driver. Everything seems to be working correctly but because the hostname address I'm using is a `Route53 CNAME` record, the CA root cert (provided by AWS) doesn't seem to be valid.

The exact error I get is:

> x509: certificate is valid for
>   ***.cluster-***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com, ***.cluster-ro-***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com, ***.***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com, not {CNAME HERE}

I know this works if I *don't* use the CNAME in the DSN... but I'm wondering if there is? This is simply the benefit of keeping the addresses clean and memorable.

Comment: In general one would set the ServerName of the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) to the canonical name.